# How to display/ retrieve all images from the database

Tags: php, image

I want to display all `Image`s from the database but my code here displays only one. How can I get them all and display in my webpage. I know I need to put a loop but I wonder where it should be.

Here's my php code so far (without loop)

```
include('../include/connect.php');
$query=ibase_query("SELECT FILEDATA FROM ARCHIVE WHERE FILE_TYPE='Image'");
$data=ibase_fetch_object($query);
if($data){
  header("Content-type:image/jpeg || image/gif || image/png || image/pjpeg");
  ibase_blob_echo($data->FILEDATA);
}
```

Comment: In sql libraries there'll be a function on the return value that'll return the next row while there are rows left. Call that in the loop while it still has rows remaining (will be another function)

Answer (score 1):

Each time you use `ibase_fetch_object` it gets the next object

so you could uset it in a **while** loop (php example) :

```
 header("Content-type:image/jpeg || image/gif || image/png || image/pjpeg");
    while ($data=ibase_fetch_object($query){


  ibase_blob_echo($data->FILEDATA);

}
```

EDIT :
following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5754018/1427338) you should have 2 separate files

Comment: it still loads only one image :(

Comment: i changed the post i was resending the header

Comment: i really appreciate your help bleuscyther, but it still gives the same result. :(

Comment: try to output the result of the query SELECT Count(*) FROM ARCHIVE WHERE FILE_TYPE='Image' to see if the query is ok

Comment: also i don think you will be able to display all of them that way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753928/how-to-display-multiple-images-blob-from-mysql-using-php

Comment: now it's giving me goosebumps. when i try to count all image files it only counts 1 but when i checked my database values, i have stored 3 image files there. anyway thanks a lot for this bleuscyther, it kinda gives me an idea now that the problem is not in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, dunno if this works but, you might as well consider use foreach loop.

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
if ($value) {
    ibase_blob_echo($value->FILEDATA);
}
}
```

Comment: i still get the same output considering that i replaced $value in the $value->FILEDATA line with $data because it does not work. :(